# Distortion in the Image with android Custom Camera

Tags: android

I want to make android custom camera in portrait mode.I havew done all the things but now my main issue is that my image is distorting with the camera.I checked all the solutions posted before but nothing helps my out.Can you please help me.My Camera Preview class is:-

```
   public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback 
  {
     private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
     private Camera mCamera;

//Constructor that obtains context and camera
public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
    super(context);
    this.mCamera = camera;

    this.mSurfaceHolder = this.getHolder();
    this.mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this); // we get notified when underlying surface is created and destroyed
    this.mSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS); //this is a deprecated method, is not requierd after 3.0
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      // left blank for now
    }

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
    mCamera.stopPreview();
    mCamera.release();
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int format,
        int width, int height) {






    // start preview with new settings
    try {



        CameraActivity a=new CameraActivity();


        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();

         parameters.set("zoom", "2.0");
           parameters.set("taking-picture-zoom", "20");




           Camera.Size size = getBestPreviewSize(width, height,parameters) ;






        // Log.w("parameters"," "+  mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes());


         parameters.setPreviewSize(size.width, size.height);



         Toast.makeText(getContext(), "width" +size.width, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         Toast.makeText(getContext(), "height" +size.height, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        int displayRotation = a.display.getRotation();



          switch (displayRotation)  {
                case Surface.ROTATION_0:     
                    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);    

                    //Log.w("enter here","aaa");break;

                case Surface.ROTATION_90:    
                    // parameters.setPreviewSize(size.width, size.height);
                    break;

                case Surface.ROTATION_180: 
                //   parameters.setPreviewSize(size.height,size.width);

                    break;

                case Surface.ROTATION_270:    
                     //parameters.setPreviewSize(size.width, size.height);

                    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(180);

                //  Log.w("enter here","aaa");
                break;

            }




        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // intentionally left blank for a test
    }
}


Camera.Size getBestPreviewSize(int width, int height, Camera.Parameters parameters) {
    Camera.Size result=null;
    float dr = Float.MAX_VALUE;
    float ratio = (float)width/(float)height;

    for (Camera.Size size : parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes()) {
        float r = (float)size.width/(float)size.height;
        if( Math.abs(r - ratio) < dr && size.width <= width && size.height <= height ) {
            dr = Math.abs(r - ratio);
            result = size;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

}

I have also use :-

```
    private Camera.Size getBestPreviewSize(int width, int height)
{
        Camera.Size result=null;    
        Camera.Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();
        for (Camera.Size size : p.getSupportedPreviewSizes()) {
            if (size.width<=width && size.height<=height || (size.height <= width && size.width <= height)) {
                if (result==null) {
                    result=size;
                } else {
                    int resultArea=result.width*result.height;
                    int newArea=size.width*size.height;

                    if (newArea>resultArea) {
                        result=size;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    return result;

}
```

but nothing solution helps me..Please help me out..?

Comment: still have the same problem, in landscape everything works fine, but portrait :/